# how to stop scheduler in laravel Server?

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I'm new to Laravel.here I'm set scheduler but how can I stop this scheduler on server ? possible or not in server ?

Comment: welcome to SO ... `sudo service cron stop`

Answer (score 1):

Just open the cron jobs in editor mode `crontab -e` and delete the line used for laravel

If you don't see the cron job set, check if it has been set by other user like from apache, or root or anyone else. In short you need to first figure out how the scheduler is currently running.

> Last option: Comment out the scheduling code.